# How to resolve Chrome driver issue in Selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

My Chrome Browser version is #79.0.8945 . Though I provide the ChromeDriver of the same version but still get an error below error stating

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created:
>   This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80

How to resolve the issue?